# PHP to call itself with a new paramter value

Tags: php

I have a PHP that receives a parameter (for example 4000) it uses to query a DB with. After executing whatever it needs to do, I want the PHP to call itself so it can do the exact same thing but this time with the new value (for example 8000). Ofocurse I need the first instance to stop/exit/halt.

How can I do this? Include is irrelevant and exec is good for other types of execution (unless I'm wrong here)

Thanks

Comment: Care to post the code you're using so far?

Comment: you could use ajax for that

Comment: DamienPirsy: How the code will matter? I just want to know how to make the PHP call itself with a different parameter.

IseNgaRt: Can you point me to somewhere I can read more about how to do it using ajax?

Comment: If you want to run one PHP script from another you can use `exec` or any other executing function. But you want something wrong. Could you explain what are you trying to do? I'm sure there is better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not required to output anything from the script, you could do the following:

- Perform the task while not running into script timeout
- Set a [location header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to the script itself with modified parameters
- exit

If you want the script to produce output, you can use the Javascript function location.href instead of the location header. For this, output something like the following snippet at the end of your script:

```
// php functionality above
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
location.href = "<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>?param=<php echo $param_value; ?>";
</script>
```

Modify this to fulfill your needs. The header is more suitable for non-interactive setups like the links2 browser, whereas the JavaScript you would use if you want to see whats going on.

Comment: The output I have is the progress so I will know something is happening. Can you point me to where I can accomplish that using js and location.href? I know js and I know href.location, I'm not sure I know how to do it all inside my php code. Thanks.

Comment: The JavaScript code is mostly plain, non-dynamic text; I will add an example.

Comment: There should be a ? before php inside the js but after adding that, it works excellently!!

Comment: @Amos Yes, of course, thank you for the information. Corrected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursive functions, which simply means calling the same function from that function. Simple example based on the numbers you gave:

```
<?php

function do_something( $arg )
{
    // Just do something (example)
    echo $arg . "\n";
    $arg = $arg + 4000;

    // Stop doing it when the argument is above 8000 
    if( $arg > 8000 )
    {
        return;
    }

    // Do it again
    do_something( $arg );
}

do_something( 4000 );
```

Comment: The problem is that the script takes too much time and the browser kills it in the middle. I want to execute it 2-3 times, each time with a different parameter's value so it won't take that long.

Comment: @Amos post the actual code, you might be chasing the wrong problem

Comment: It's a code that in a loop it takes info from a db, calls http request, parse it and insert it into a DB. It takes time and it should take time (long process) so I want it to run in bulks. Now I simply calls it manually 3-4 times, I was wondering if I could make it automatiically

Answer (score 0):

You can make the script call itself by using the header() method.

Let's say you want to retrieve a batch of 24 rows at every run of a script named whatever.php.

You tell whatever.php to look out for a $_GET parameter. If there is none, you tell it to start from zero when querying the database ("...LIMIT 24"). After you've done what you needed to use header() method in order to call whatever.php again:

```
header('Location:whatever.php?offset=25');
```

Now the whatever.php, when called, will know that it must impose an offset to the sql LIMIT ("...LIMIT 25, 24"). After the script done it's job again, you call it again with the header() method:

```
header('Location:whatever.php?offset=50');
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Will not work if the script produces any output before redirecting.

Comment: I didn't know it matters :)